# convert array of numbers in array of strings using map

Tags: javascript, lodash

im using lodash, and im trying to convert a array of numbers in strings, but only convert the numbers since in my array there are null values. I tried using map of lodash in than map from javascript but is messing up the null values.

Example of array:
[1245, 5845, 4585, null, null]

code:

```
var meds = _.map(lines,'med_id').map(String);
```

Result: ["1245", "5845", "4585", "null", "null"];

Should be: ["1245", "5845", "4585", null, null];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to test the type of the value before calling `String`

```
var meds = _.map(lines, 'med_id').map(function(x) {
    return typeof x == 'number' ? String(x) : x;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) will convert anything it takes into a string. You need to make a custom function that only generates a string if the value isn't null.

```
_.map(lines, 'med_id').map(function(x) {
  if (x !== null) {
    x = x.toString();
  }
  return x;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In looking at: https://lodash.com/docs#map

it looks like:

```
function toInts(n){
    if(isNaN(n)){
       return null;
    }else{
      return n;
    }
}
_.map(lines,'med_id').map(lines,toInts);
```

would do the trick.
(Not Tested)